# Why practically the same path written in different forms doesn't works correct?

Tags: python, html, django

I am working in one django project.
I am trying to show image that is saved in Django models attribute (ImageFielf), and it's path is:
../projectname/appname/static/img/imgname.png

Considering that,I write in HTML code that:

```
class="result-item-preview fadeIn animated " style="background-image:url('../../projectname/appname/static/img/1202296.jpg'), url('../static/img/default-movie.png');
```

But this doesen't works.
It only works if it is written in usually form:

```
class="result-item-preview fadeIn animated " style="background-image:url('../static/img/1202296.jpg'), url('../static/img/default-movie.png');
```

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

In the Django docs they advise to use static template tag,
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

```
style="background-image:url({% static 'img/1202296.jpg' %}), url({% static 'img/default-movie.png' %});"
```

Now about the question itself: why the first method is not working? This is because the server that serves your web app has no clue about the directory structure in your Django project, hence it doesn't know where to find '../../projectname/appname/static/img/1202296.jpg'.

The second method is working because you defined the location of static files in the Django project settings, so the web server knows how to find static files and how to server them.